# Как остановить прокрутку ScrollRect в нужном месте в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Что необходимо сделать, чтобы область Контента при `ScrollRect` останавливалась (snapping) в нужных позициях, а не проматывалась по инерции (при её использовании) дальше?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как на картинке выше. Как только Вид 2 (Вид 3, Вид1) попадает в видимую зону, нужно оставить скролл. Т.е. не по нажатию на экран, а при определенной позиции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется снаппинг.

я это делал вот таким образом:

(*внимание решение будет работать корректно при условии, что если все элементы скролла будут **одинаковой ширины***)

```
public class Snap : MonoBehaviour
{
    //объект в котором находятся все элементы скролла
    //а сам PARENT_content назначен в компонент ScrollRect в поле Content
    public Transform PARENT_content;
    //это пустой GameObject который нужно создать как дочерний объект к вашему объекту на котором назначен ScrollRect
    //далее этот centralPoint нужно расположить на канвасе так как нужно вам - относительно этой точки и будет снаппинг элементов скролла
    public Transform centralPoint;
    //тут будем хранить расстояние между центром и каждым элементом скролла
    private List<float> distancesToCenter = new List<float>();
    //тут храним расстояние между родительским объектом элементов скролла и всех элем. скролла
    public List<float> distancesToScroll = new List<float>();
    //индекс элемента с минимальным расстоянием до центра
    public int indexMinDist;
    //происходит ли драг скролла
    private bool dragging;

    private void Update()
    {
        CalcDistanceScrollToPhoto();
        photoSnap();
    }

    //это метод нужно вызвать через компонент Event Trigger -> на событие Begin Drag
    //Event Trigger нужно назначит на объект в котором компонент ScrollRect
    //этот метод будет вызван на момент начала драга
    public void BeginDrag()
    {
        dragging = true;
        distancesToCenter.Clear();
    }

    //это метод нужно вызвать через компонент Event Trigger -> на событие End Drag
    //Event Trigger нужно назначит на объект в котором компонент ScrollRect
    //этот метод будет вызван на момент конца драга (когда отпустят кнопку мыши)
    public void EndDragPhoto()
    {
        //вычисляем дистанцию между скролл-контент точкой и фото
        CalcDistanceScrollToPhoto();

        //получаем дистанцию между центром и каждой фотографией
        for (int i = 0; i < PARENT_content.childCount; i++)
        {
            //вычисляем и получаем абсолютное значение
            distancesToCenter.Add(Mathf.Abs(centralPoint.position.x - PARENT_content.GetChild(i).position.x));
        }
        //вычисляем минимальный индекс к центру
        for (int i = 0; i < distancesToCenter.Count; i++)
        {
            if (distancesToCenter[i] == distancesToCenter.Min()) { indexMinDist = i; }
        }

        dragging = false;
    }

    //снаппинг (подгонка) фото к центру
    void photoSnap()
    {
        //если скролл не драгается
        if (dragging == false)
        {
            //перемещаем контент-объект с со всеми элементами (центровка самого ближнего к центру элемента)
            float posX = Mathf.Lerp(PARENT_content.position.x, centralPoint.position.x - distancesToScroll[indexMinDist], Time.deltaTime * 20);
            Vector2 pos = new Vector2(posX, PARENT_content.position.y);
            PARENT_content.position = pos;
        }
    }

    //получаем дистанцию каждой фотографии до скролл-объекта
    public void CalcDistanceScrollToPhoto()
    {
        distancesToScroll.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < PARENT_content.childCount; i++)
        {
            //вычисляем дистанцию между скролл-контент точкой и фото
            distancesToScroll.Add(Mathf.Abs(PARENT_content.position.x - PARENT_content.GetChild(i).position.x));
        }
    }
}
```

в комментариях достаточно подробно все описано, но еще добавлю, что этот скрипт нужно назначит **на родительский объект элементов скролла**, т.е. на тот объект который будет назначен в компонент **ScrollRect** в качестве **Content**

так же нужно будет дописать в самом вверху пространство имен `using System.Linq;` что бы в коде воспользоватся Linq-методом `Min`

вот такие настройки для объекта с компонентом **ScrollRect**, обратите внимание на настройки компонента **EventTrigger**:

[image: настройки объекта в котором ScrollRect компонент]

так же вам нужно будет добавить в публичные поля **Snap** скрипта  в инспекторе нужные объекты соответственно,

это для **PARENT_content** - в комментах листинга я описал, что это родительский контент-объект всех элементов скролла,

**centralPoint** - центральный объект относительного которого будет происходить снап элементов (*читайте комменты скрипта*), расположите его по центру экрана, ну или так как считаете нужным, в теле вопроса вы писали про центровку элемента который *попал в видимую зону*, так вот как раз с помощью объекта centralPoint вы сможете это отрегулировать, меняя местоположение centralPoint

остальные публичные поля трогать не стоит

если все сделать как описал я, у вас будет работать снаппинг скролла в реальном времени

добавлю еще пару изображений показывающих иерархию объектов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Доброго времени суток. Вроде бы всё сделал, как вы указали: Все элементы скролла одной ширины; Скрипт назначен на родительский объект элементов скролла; настройки назначены; создан пустой объект, относительно которого снаппим. Но скролл идёт только в одну сторону - в моём случаем влево. И кроме всего этого проматывает весь Content в конец, хотя пустой объект назначен на первом Виде.

Comment: Должно все работать, я создал пустую сцену и сделал все тоже самое, у меня все снаппится хорошо, проверьте пожалуйста назначили ли вы компонент Event Trigger в тот объект в котором компонент Scroll Rect (он есть у меня на изображении выше), проверьте назначили ли вы его правильно, так же в ответ добавлю дополнительные изображения для показа иерархии объектов

Comment: Благодарю. Теперь всё получилось. Судя по всему, где-то что-то упустил сначала. Спасибо и всего наилучшего! :)